# Error:android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x1

Tags: android, user-interface, user-experience, butterknife

**Am getting an error saying resource id can't be found tried tracing the problem the code seems fine**

This area contains my class that uses the xml resource below to show all  the necessary elements anyone who can help to tell me why am getting such an error

```
    @Bind(R.id.showfirstname)
    MyEditText Myfirstname;

    @Bind(R.id.showlastname)
    MyEditText Mylastname;

    @Bind(R.id.showEmail)
    MyEditText Myemail;

    @Bind(R.id.profilephone)
    MyEditText Mytel;



private  Source mDataSource = new Source(this);

    Cursor userDataCursor;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.user_profile);
        getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);


        ButterKnife.bind(this);

        mDataSource.open();

        userDataCursor = mDataSource.selectUserData();
        userDataCursor.moveToFirst();


        Myfirstname.setText(userDataCursor.getColumnIndex("firstname"));
        Myfirstname.setEnabled(false);
        Mylastname.setText(userDataCursor.getColumnIndex("lastname"));
      Mylastname.setEnabled(false);
       Myemail.setText(userDataCursor.getColumnIndex("email"));
    Myemail.setEnabled(false);
     Mytel.setText(userDataCursor.getColumnIndex("tel"));
     Mytel.setEnabled(false);




        mDataSource.close();

    }
```

Comment: I guess data is null, Check *userDataCursor* is null are not, print log *userDataCursor.getColumnIndex("firstname")* then you can able to trace problem ease.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `getColumnIndex` method won't give you the value of that column. It only gives you the index of that column in your database.

You should do it like this:

`userDataCursor.getString(userDataCursor.getColumnIndex("firstname"));`